# How to get only the capital X height from FormattedText?

Tags: wpf, formatted-text

My conclusion is that this can not be done as I can not seem to access the ascender height of a formattedtext object. As a rough approximation, I am using:

```
public static double GetCapitalX(this FormattedText text)
    {
         double bottom = text.Height + text.OverhangAfter;      // bottom most inked pixel

        /* this is wrong since the Extent includes the ascender height. But it's the best I can do. */
         double capitalX = text.Extent - (bottom - text.Baseline);
         return capitalX;
    }
```

Is there a better (more accurate) way? Any help is appreciated.